# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'; 
import AboutPage from './pages/aboutPage'

const history = createHistory();  

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router history={ history }>
     <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={ App }/>
      <Route path='/about' element={ AboutPage }/>
     </Routes>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Бьюсь с этой ошибкой уже немалое время. То ли я дбоеб, то ли лыжи не едут, но гуглинг ни к чему не привел.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код файла Router.js: https://jsfiddle.net/mustmusk/kcpmxzaw/

React v17.0.2, React-router v5.2.1, React-router-dom v6.0.1

Comment: Что-то не так с createHistory(). Вы уверены, что объект не "пустой"? Пробовали выводить в консоль содержимое history?

Comment: Покажите `createHistory`. И код приведите текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у Вас неправильная версия `history`, установите явно версию `5.x.x`

Вот вырезка из их доки:

```
Version 5 is used in React Router version 6.

Version 4 is used in React Router versions 4 and 5.
```

P.S: наверное нет смысла использовать `react-router` и `react-router-dom` одновременно:)